# error vsim-3170: ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.3d while starting simulation

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

On ModelSim I'm not able to start a simulation, for any of my projects.

I have installed ModelSim on 2 different machines, and both give me the same error message:

For a simple edge detector project, here's what happens in the console after I do "Simulation - Start Simulation":

```
vsim -gui work.edgedet_tb
# vsim -gui 
# Start time: 22:48:53 on Nov 10,2014
# Loading std.standard
# Loading std.textio(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_1164(body)
# Loading ieee.numeric_std(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_arith(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_unsigned(body)
# Loading work.edgedet_tb(structural)
# ** Error: (vsim-3170) Could not find 'C:/Users/Andy/Google Drive/DigitaleSynthese/5-11-14/appl-layer/edgedetector/work.edgedet(behav)'.
# 
# Error loading design
```

The code compiles with no errors/warnings.

If I check the work-folder in the project's directory it looks like it contains a bunch of standard files but no project-related files. In previous projects which I have made in the past (with an earlier version) it would contain more files with names conforming to the project.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The file path is pretty long, and I have once experienced a problem with ModelSim due to a long file path, so it may be worth trying with a shorter file path.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However same problem with "C:\vhdlprojects".

Comment: Read up about the "vlib" and "vmap" commands. It may be looking in the wrong place for your Work library, something like `vmap work c:/path/to/right/place` may be what you need.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond, the vlib/vmap commands helped me better understand that there had to be another problem because everything looked correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out other projects *did* simulate, so it was a small error in the source code:

```
edgedet.vhd:
ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF edgedet IS

edgedet_tb.vhd:
for uut : edgedet use entity work.edgedet(behav);
```

Comment: ... so it was looking in the right place, but for the wrong name! I'm sure we've all been there at some stage...